# It is possible to detect a crash of the Java VM on its exit code?

Tags: java, process, exit-code

Is there a specific exit code of the Java VM that returns if the Java process crash? I want restart the Java process if its terminate through an crash. If there is a normal termination for example through a kill signal then I want not to restart.